# Angular10 Reactive Form to PDF using jsPDF

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, jspdf, html2canvas, angular10

I'm working on angular reactive form and I'm trying to convert the entire HTML form into a PDF using Html2Canvas and jsPDF.

My form is scrollable and the part that is visible is showing white and, part invisible is getting greyed out.

Is there any way to show the entire form without greyed out?

I tried googling but it's not showing anywhere.

```js
const data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert'); 
const dataHeight = data.clientHeight; 
const dataWidth = data.clientWidth; 
const ratio = dataHeight / dataWidth; 

html2canvas(data, {scale: 1}).then(canvas => { 
     const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); 
     const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); 
     // A4 size page of PDF 
     const width = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth(); 
     let height = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight(); 
     height = ratio * width; 
     pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width - 20, height); 
     pdf.save('new-file.pdf'); 
});
```

Appreciate the help for the solution

Comment: Hi Archit, can you please add a screenshot so that everyone can understand what you are doing. Also please add the code snippet that you used to convert the form to pdf.

Comment: I'm not able to attach the screenshot for this